# why does JavaScript arguments have length property but other objects don't?

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

Why does the below code have the `length` property (specifically the object created by passing arguments to the function):

```
function somefunction() {
  var a = arguments;
  return a;
}

var b = somefunction('a','b','c')
```

> b
>     { '0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c' }
>     b.length
>     3

Whereas if a normal object is created it doesn't have the `length` property:

```
var someobj = {
  '0': 'abc',
  '1': 'def',
  '2': 'efg'
}
```

> someobj.length
>      undefined

Comment: Arguments is an Array-like object, so it has length. A plain object doesn't. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments So the arguments object isn't a plain object.

Comment: If a plain object had a `length`, you'd run into problems when you want to use that property for other purposes. This isn't an issue with indexed collections.

Comment: That's the way the language works. Arrays and array-like objects have a "length" property that contains the number of numeric-indexed properties. Plain objects don't. To find out "why" you'd need to read some commentary on the language design or something, and it won't help you much in writing JavaScript code.

Comment: it just makes sense to have arguments.length available, to easily know how many got passed

Comment: What browser/js environment (version) are you using? I'm getting a very different output when logging an arguments object.

Comment: Hi Bergi , I am using node to test the javascript code. The usuage is node <filename.js>

Answer (score 2):

`var myObject = {a: "x", length: 5}` has a .length property as well. There is nothing special about [`arguments.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length). Well, maybe that it is [non-enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties), which is the reason it did not show up in your `console.log` that might have confused you. You can reproduce that as well:

```
var someobj = Object.defineProperty({
    '0': 'abc',
    '1': 'def',
    '2': 'efg',
    'length': 'whatever'
}, 'length', {enumerable:false});
console.log(someobj); // {0: "abc", 1: "def", 2: "efg"}
console.log(someobj.length); // whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object passed to a function is an Array-like object which has an [arguments.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length) method, this is in order to retrieve the number of parameters passed to a function*. This is different to the [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) method which specifies the number of arguments **expected** by the function.

```
function myFunc(param) {
        return arguments.length;
}

myFunc('param1', 'param2'); // 2

myFunc.length; // 1
```

* *The functional and dynamic nature of the Javascript language allows for a variable number of parameters to be passed to a function. In order to affectively determine a functions parameters, we use the arguments object.*

In order to retrieve the length of an object (it's own properties) you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
let myObj = {
     a: "one",
     b: "two"
};

Object.keys(myObj).length; // 2
```